# How does Java manage summertime?

Tags: java

As many of you many know, In Europe we have a summertime and a wintertime. Twice a year, the clocks in all EU Member States are switched from winter to summertime (on the last Sunday in March) and back from summer to wintertime (on the last Sunday in October) (more info [here](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/themes/summertime_en)). Now, the European Commision is about to propose to get rid of those clock changes.

In Java, we have Calendars and, a calendar always knows the correct timeZone (i.e. GMT+1 for summertime and GMT+2 for wintertime). How does Java manage this? And, if it's changed, how would it affect to our systems?

So, as I see on comments, there shouldn't be any changes because Java uses System Time and it's setted by NTP, right?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Java time is based on the native system time.

Comment: A. I think you mean GMT. B. There shouldn't be any changes

Comment: You are asking two distinct questions here. One is about how Java manages timezones in general, which I think is too broad as it is asked right now. The other is how Java and/or systems using Java will handle a political change in the EU that abolishes daylight-saving. Since no one here (as far as I know) can predict the future, I don't see how we could give you a useful answer besides speculation.

Comment: Summertime is about to be abolished, not long and we don’t have to worry no more

Comment: Java has the *TimeZone* concept. That is basically all you need to know. For any further usage of that, you have to study that topic, to understand how it applies to your use case. The duplicated questions give some insight in what that means.

Comment: @bambam Maybe in some countries, not everywhere.

Comment: Since I can't answer, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzdata-versions-138805.html  for examples of how changes are routinely handled. Note Java and IANA/Olson use the US term 'daylight savings time' = DST not 'summer time'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will say by `java.util.TimeZone` .

`TimeZone` represents a time zone offset, and also figures out daylight savings.
Typically, you get a `TimeZone` using `getDefault` which creates a `TimeZone` based on the time zone where the program is running. For example, for a program running in Japan, `getDefault` creates a `TimeZone object` based on Japanese Standard Time.

You can also get a `TimeZone` using `getTimeZone` along with a time zone ID. For instance, the time zone ID for the U.S. Pacific Time zone is "America/Los_Angeles". So, you can get a U.S. Pacific Time TimeZone object with:

```
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
```